# Unable to save audio file to node in drupal 7

Tags: services, files

I am attaching an audio file to node using services 3 in drupal 7. When I hit my URL:

www.mysite/api/nid/attach_file

I get an error:

STATUS 500 Internal Server Error: An error occurred (23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'field_attach_audio_activity_display' cannot be null

I also tried by setting field_attach_audio_activity_display to 1 in POST parameters. But it gave same error.

Anyone who knows please help me to solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: This error seems to relate to how you create a node and attach a file, thather than the services. You need to compare what value you want to see in that field, and what the node gets. If it should be FALSE, 0, or -1, you shoul dmake it that, not an empty value (NULL).

Comment: I am using services 3 because I am creating nodes from my android app. I can successfully create a node from my app but after creating a node, I want to update that node with media (Images,Audio and videos) files. I can successfully attach images and videos to a node from app but when I try to attach an audio file I get above error.

Comment: Let me tell you what I am doing:  First of all I create a node from my app with this url www.mysite/endpoint/node and it returns me nid, then by using this nid I attach a media file using this url www.mysite/endpoint/nid/attach_file. It attaches images and video but gives an error when I try to attach audio file.